# How to deploy or make PHP program accessible to someone far/anyone

Tags: php, mysql, database, deployment, accessible

I have this PHP program and I would want it to be accessed by a certain person on his/her own computer wherever he is. What I have tried so far:

1. A person was able to access my program/site on his own computer using my IP address but the condition was we were connected to the same WiFi/Internet connection.
2. A person was able to access my program/site on his own computer but what I did was convert my PHP program into an executable file and made him install WAMP. I also sent him the .sql files necessary because my program also uses database connectivity. What I did not like about this was the level of effort needed and that the .exe file product did not fully capture the features (such as the CSS) of my program.

What could be possible solutions to this problem? I want someone to access my program without installing something and without me buying a public domain or something like that.

Comment: you can use free hosting to host your php stuff. they usually gives along a free dns too but the customer service is terrible. they can access your site anywhere usign the free dns given. you can try hostinger or 000web but these 2 hosting uses php version 5.4 and lower.

Comment: If you keep a computer running you can use that as a webhost.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Do you have a link for the specific instructions on how to do it?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Can-I-host-my-own-website-with-my-own-Computer